# ios sharedsession error on completion

Tags: ios, swift, swift-playground

I am blocked by this nasty error while learning iOS sharedSession singleton and async calls

here is my code

```
let baseUrl = NSURL(string: "https://api.forecast.io/forecast/\(apiKey)/")
let forecast = NSURL(string: "47.856223,-122.272590", relativeToURL: baseUrl)
let sharedSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask =
sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL( forecast, completionHandler:
    { (loction: <#NSURL!#>, response: <#NSURLResponse!#>, error: <#NSError!#>) -> Void in
        println(response);
    })

}
```

here is where error happens

```
{ (loction: <#NSURL!#>, response: <#NSURLResponse!#>, error: <#NSError!#>) -> Void in
                println(response);
            })
```

here is error

```
1-expected an identifier to name generic parameter
2- expect parameter type following :
```

Comment: Is that your real code? You have to replace the placeholders with actual types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add placeholders with appropriate variables.Replace your code with following

```
sharedSession.downloadTaskWithURL(forecast , completionHandler:{(location:NSURL!, response:NSURLResponse!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
    println(response);

 })
```